# iOS, Launch Screen goes black after loading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I accidentally deleted my Launch `Screen.xib`. I have created a new one which runs on startup as it should. However, before it would show the launch screen then go to my `GameViewController.swift` file. Now, it just goes black. I've put a breakpoint in every `.swift` file I have to see if it goes to any of them, and it just seems to get lost. I can't seem to find where to set where it should go after the Launch Screen.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click your `Project Targets` and check your `Info Plist` file. Whether the `Launch screen interface file base name` having your `XIB filename` or `not`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! When I erased the LaunchScreen, it also erased this line and the "Main storyboard file base name" line. So I had to re-add that one. Thanks so much for your help!